How is the lightning effect of the Rechargeable Battery achieved in Plants vs. Zombies 2
How is the lightning effect of the lighting reed achieved in Plants vs. Zombies 2, which produces different electrical arcs depending on the target's position?
Is this achieved through piecing together hand-drawn art assets or through pre-existing animation libraries
